# Command to Change DB Column in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, date, scaffolding

Is there a quick console command I can run to change the type I have for an object? It's currently a Ruby Date type, but I would like it to be a Ruby Time type.

I started with this scaffold command:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Post title:string content:text postdate:date
```

But wish I would have done the following:

```
$ rails generate scaffold Post title:string content:text postdate:time
```

Is there a command and can run to make the update?

Comment: Is there a reason why the default :timestamps (created_at, updated_at) aren't sufficient?

Comment: Yeah because the postdate could be backdated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes you have to write some actual code, even in Rails. Try creating migration and then using `change_column` method. Something like

```
change_column :my_table, :my_column, :new_type
```

You put this in your db migration file, not in shell.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want the mistake to be a permanent part of the migration set, simply migrate down (`rake db:rollback`), edit your migration file, and migrate back up (`rake db:migrate`).

**Edit**: To answer your question about there being a single command? Yes, there is. After editing your migration:

```
rake db:migrate:redo
```

This runs the "down" followed by the "up" in just one command.

Answer (score 0):

Three steps to change the type of a column:

Step 1:

Generate a new migration file using this code:

```
rails g migration sample_name_change_column_type
```

Step 2:

Go to `/db/migrate` folder and edit the migration file you made. There are two different solutions.

1. ```
   def change
       change_column(:table_name, :column_name, :new_type)
   end
   ```

2.

```
    def up
        change_column :table_name, :column_name, :new_type
    end

    def down
        change_column :table_name, :column_name, :old_type
    end
```

Step 3:

Don't forget to do this command:

```
rake db:migrate
```

I have tested this solution for Rails 4 and it works well.